# Openlayer: Two finger movement (dragPan)

Tags: openlayers

Google recently reworked there maps mobile behaviour. Now on mobile you have can move the map with two fingers. (see [map-simple](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple) example on a phone, not with any browser emulator!).

I want to implement the same feature in openlayer. Detecting mobile (with e.g. [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/)), disabling the [`dragPan`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29097178/how-to-disable-dragpan-in-openlayers-3) is not the problem, but how can I write my own [`ol.interaction.Interaction`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.html) to work with two fingers?

I looked into the [doku](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.html) and didn't find any examples, where to start.

Answer (score 2):

The drag interactions typically come with a 'condition' option. You provide a function taking one parameter (**ol.MapBrowserEvent**) and returning a boolean indicating whether or not the interaction should apply.

The **ol.MapBrowserEvent** wraps the original browser event which means you can just look for the touches array on that and check if it is of length 2.

```
<script>
    var map = new ol.Map({
        interactions: [
            new ol.interaction.DragPan({

                // This comment marks the beginning of the code of interest.

                condition: function(olBrowserEvent) {
                    if (olBrowserEvent.originalEvent.touches)
                        return olBrowserEvent.originalEvent.touches.length === 2;
                    return false;
                }

                // This comment marks the end.

            })
        ],
        layers: [
            // Your layers.
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [-33519607, 5616436],
            rotation: -Math.PI / 8,
            zoom: 8
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: For me `olBrowserEvent.originalEvent.touches` was undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer says to use `ol.BrowserEvent.originalEvent.touches`.
When debugging I have found that the event type is `pointerdown`. I have seen sources that say that the pointer down event does not have a `touches` element, which explains what I was seeing and what Josh Mc commented about.

I decided to get around this I would count the number of touches myself:

```js
    this.olMap.on('pointerdown', function (event) {
      TTT.cuncurrentTouches += 1
    })
    this.olMap.on('pointerup', function (event) {
      TTT.cuncurrentTouches -= 1
      if (TTT.concurrentTouches < 0) {
        TTT.cuncurrentTouches = 0
      }
    })
```

Also I found that the previous solution resulted in all the map interactions being removed, and just the pan added. I didn't want them all to be removed; instead I just wanted to replace the `DragPan` interaction. I did this by creating a default action list without `DragPan` and adding in my own `DragPan`. This will cause the interaction order evaluation to change but it seemed to work on my laptop and mobile phone testing.

```js
    var interactions = defaultInteractions({ dragPan: false })
    interactions.extend([
      new DragPan({
        condition: function (olBrowserEvent) {
          if (olBrowserEvent.originalEvent.pointerType !== 'touch') {
            return true // Mouse scroll will always work
          }
          if (TTT.cuncurrentTouches === 2) {
            return true
          }
        }
      })
    ])
    
    this.olMap = new Map({
      target: this.$refs['openlayer-map-root'],
      interactions: interactions,
      layers: [
        // adding a background tiled layer
        new TileLayer({
          source: new OSM() // tiles are served by OpenStreetMap
        }),
        this.vectorLayer
      ],
    
      view: new View({
        zoom: 16,
        center: fromLonLat(center),
        constrainResolution: true
      })
    })
```

Comment: After posting this I found https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/two-finger-pan-scroll.html?q=scroll which has a good example.